# How to notify site admin when user registers with a specific field checked

Tags: users

My case site has `student` and `teacher` accounts (teacher/student radio buttons). When user registers as a teacher, admin has to be notified so that admin performs further checks to accept the account.

How can I do this programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this easily using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module:

1. Create a rule that triggers 'After saving a new account'
2. Add a condition that determines whether the value of the field is set to the teacher value (Using 'Data Comparison').
3. Add an action element to send a notification email (System > Send Mail).